# Data grid pagination not showing in the angularjs

Tags: angularjs, datagrid, pagination

As per [this](http://angular-data-grid.github.io/demo/bootstrap/) link i have used all the libs and functions but i can't see the pagination buttons as like above link demo.

I am loading data from the angularjs get method, After data retrieved i am showing this grid. Everything is working good but only pagination is not working.

Item per page is showing only pagination numbers only not showing.

This my HTML code:

```
<div grid-data id='test' grid-options="gridOptions" grid-actions="gridActions">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 text-right">
            <form class="form-inline pull-right margin-bottom-basic">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <grid-pagination max-size="5" boundary-links="true" class="pagination-sm" total-items="paginationOptions.totalItems" ng-model="paginationOptions.currentPage" ng-change="reloadGrid()" items-per-page="paginationOptions.itemsPerPage"></grid-pagination>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table media-table-data">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="sortable">
                    Media Type
                </th>
                <th sortable="title" class="sortable">
                    Media Name
                </th>
                <th class="sortable">
                    Created By
                </th>
                <th class="sortable">
                    Created Date
                </th>
                <th class="sortable">
                    Last Modified
                </th>
                <th class="sortable">
                    Status
                </th>
                <!-- <th class="st-sort-disable th-dropdown">
                                                <select class="form-control width-15"
                                                        filter-by="statusDisplay"
                                                        filter-type="select"
                                                        ng-model="status"
                                                        ng-change="filter()">
                                                    <option value="">All Statuses</option>
                                                    <option ng-repeat="option in statusOptions track by option.value"
                                                            value="{{option.value}}">{{option.text}}
                                                    </option>
                                                </select>

                                            </th> -->
                <th class="sortable">
                    Action
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-show="!medialength">
                <td colspan="7" align="center">No Media Available</td>
            </tr>
            <tr grid-item>
                <td>
                    <a href="" ng-click="goToPlay(item.id,'member.play')">
                                                    <span class="filetype" ng-class="{'videofile': item.mediaType==1 || item.mediaType==3,'audiofile': item.mediaType==2}"></span>
                                            <!--         <span style="background:url ({{ item.thumbnail ? item.thumbnail : '/assets/images/grey.png' }})" ></span> -->


                                            <span class="media-thumbline" style="background:url({{ item.thumbnail ? item.thumbnail : '/assets/images/grey.png' }})"></span>
                                                    <span class="media-time">{{ item.mediaFileDuration | toMinSec }}</span>
                                                </a>
                </td>
                <td ng-bind="item.title"></td>
                <td ng-bind="userData.name"></td>
                <td>{{ item.createdAt | date : "MMM dd, yyyy" }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.updatedAt | date : "MMM dd, yyyy" }}</td>
                <td>
                    <label class="inprogresstext" ng-show="item.mediaStatus==1">
                        <i class="fas fa-sync fa-spin"></i> Upload inprogress</label>
                    <label class="inprogresstext" ng-show="item.mediaStatus==2">
                        <i class="fas fa-sync fa-spin"></i> Transcription inprogress</label>
                    <label class="completedtext" ng-show="item.mediaStatus==3">
                        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> Completed</label>
                    <label class="failedtext" ng-show="item.mediaStatus==4">
                        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Upload Failed</label>
                    <label class="failedtext" ng-show="item.mediaStatus==5">
                        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Transcription Failed </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="dropdown drop-position" title="more">
                        <a href="" class="vertical-more more-icon-button dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdwnicon-menu">
                            <li><a ng-href="{{item.mediaFile}}" download><i class="material-icons">file_download</i> Download</a></li>
                            <li><a ng-click="openeditModal(item)"><i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>Edit</a></li>
                            <li><a ng-hide="item.mediaStatus==2 || !item.mediaStatus==1" ng-click="openDeleteModal(item)" title="Delete {{item.fileType == 2 ? 'Audio' : 'Video'}}"><i class="material-icons">delete</i>Delete</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 table-footer-page" ng-if="medialength">
        <div class="pager-btn-section">
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <grid-pagination max-size="5" boundary-links="true" class="pagination-sm" total-items="paginationOptions.totalItems" ng-model="paginationOptions.currentPage" ng-change="reloadGrid()" items-per-page="paginationOptions.itemsPerPage"></grid-pagination>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group items-per-page">
                    <label for="itemsOnPageSelect2">Items per page:</label>
                    <select id="itemsOnPageSelect2" class="form-control input-sm" ng-init="paginationOptions.itemsPerPage = '10'" ng-model="paginationOptions.itemsPerPage" ng-change="reloadGrid()">
                        <option>10</option>
                        <option>25</option>
                        <option>50</option>
                        <option>75</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add 'pagination' dependency injector in my module, Thats why pagination is not loaded. Now it's fixed.